# how to send email using smtp in c#?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have a list of data from a database and  I have Email Id's in database, i have to send email to those ID's where if its retention date is tomorrow means i have to send an intimation email as reminder by today,i want to send email, and i will use service to send it daily, but my email part is not working..below is my code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SendingEmail
{
    public class SendingMail
    {
      public static void SendMail(string recipient, string subject, string 
      body, string attachmentFilename)
        {
           //method to send email 
           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            try
            {
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "my password");
                string From = "my email@gmail.com";
                string To = "email.com";
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
                mail.Body = "mail with attachment";
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(From, To);
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment
                (@"C:\Users\rahul.chakrabarty\Desktop\logg.txt");
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            //To cathch Exception
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("unable to send" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My error is "unable to sendsystem.InvalidOperationException: A from address must be specified"..This is my error

Comment: I'd have removed those comments affecting the formatting tbh; they're just noise

Comment: AFAIK an email address can't have spaces. change `string From = "my email@gmail.com";` to `string From = "myEmail@gmail.com";`

Comment: I was assuming that was just him obfuscating his email address..

Comment: please set the sender and receiver of the mail variable. you accidently created a new mailmessage.

Comment: Try adding `mail.From = From;` and `mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));` and remove `MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(From, To);`.

Comment: no its not working i am getting error,though i use gmail and other thing

Answer (score 1):

You said

```
String from = "my email@gmail...
```

But nowhere have you actually assigned this string to the `mail.From` property - you've gone and made a new MailMessage using that from address, and called it msg:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(From, To)
```

but you aren't sending the `msg` mail, you're sending the `mail` mail:

```
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

The same problem exists with the To address on the `mail` variable

Basically, the code is all messed up: you make TWO MailMessage objects, set half the necessary things on one, the other half of necessary things on the other, and then try to send one of them with incomplete details. It's kinda like you copied and pasted two different tutorials together but didn't get enough of either of them to get a complete MailMessage ready for sending

I could have fixed this all up for you and posted working code, but I haven't for two reasons: 1) it's very easy to do these small changes yourself, and 2) I want YOU to do it as a learning exercise rather than just giving you the answer :)

Make sure you don't put a space in the email address either

Comment: yeah sorry i did changes so i dint see but though i corrected now,, i dint get any exception..but i dint get anymail too

Comment: Check the junk mail? Test mails with attachments look so much like those "here is your UPS invoice <virus word document attached>" ones hat they just get straight to the bin. Maybe even gmail didn't send it, if you're using their service.. can't tell what details of your post you have edited to hide real info!

Comment: getting error as "unable to sendsystem.net.mail.smtpException"

Comment: It doesn't help to just tell he type of exception. What is the contents of the exception's .Message property? Like you posted before "a from address must be specified" - this an example of an  error message in the .Message property. The error message will be needed to work out the problem

Comment: Failure sending mail. a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,or established connection has failed because the connected host has failed to respond 64.233.167.108:587. and in the line SmtpServer.Send(mail);

Comment: Gmail is ignoring you or an interim firewall is blocking your connection. Try another mail server that is a bit more friendly, or try later, or investigate what gmail's servers do when they think someone is using them to spam. If you're sending lots of mails, consider signing up for a dedicated bulk email sending service. Gmail is probably not a good service to use for your intended purpose

Comment: no its not working i am getting error,though i use other thing